# Wrong order of execution of tests

Tags: scala, scalatest, specs2

I have the following test code:

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.specification.{BeforeExample, Before, Scope}

class TestSpec extends Specification with BeforeExample {

  def before = println("before!!!!")

  "Test" should {
    "run before 1" in {
      println("test 1")
      success
    }
    "run before 2" in {
      println("test 2")
      success
    }
    "run before 3" in {
      println("test 3")
      success
    }
  }

}
```

I expect something like:

```
before!!!!
test 1
before!!!!
test 2
before!!!!
test 3
...
```

But get the output:

```
before!!!!
before!!!!
before!!!!
test 3
test 2
test 1Test should
run before 1
run before 2
run before 3
```

Why such a strange order?
Tests are run in parallel mode?

In this synthetic example it does not matter. But if `before` make a database cleanup or something else this execution order break testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

specs2 executes tests concurrently by default (see the docs [here](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Runners.html)). Add the `sequential` keyword in order to execute the tests sequentially:

```
class TestSpec extends Specification with BeforeExample {
 sequential
 // your tests
}
```